# Form data is not updating array using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a small bulletin board project and I'm trying to update my array with a new board post that is submitted by a form. For some reason it's not being added to the array. Logging shows that the form data is being picked up by my bulletinboard component but it's not updating the state.

Got any suggestions?

[Code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/DougJones866/bbs/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000i2666j076ktjs%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000e26664l816ogh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000g26665tbxpsl6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000h2666hix6st9v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.83094408457185%252C46.16905591542815%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clmjib341000e26664l816ogh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000e26664l816ogh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmks5ipd06012665i6zjyklu%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib340000d2666y37h4q23%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2520%28DELETED%29%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2520%28DELETED%29%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjibiob00tn2666r8m67tr8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.jsx%2520%28DELETED%29%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjibyv200yc2666ib71ihgq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjiwmz002ou2665gskbhxgu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles%252FApp.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmkpeaa103c52665a5fwbg4m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles%252FCard.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmkpenu804012665kdov65do%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FBulletinBoard.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmks5ipd06012665i6zjyklu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FCard.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmks86iy06fj2665eqijeh8w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles%252FPostForm.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmksqc9w07ld2665yjce1t41%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FPosts.jsx%2520%28DELETED%29%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqia2i300rr2666iv4mcutv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles%252FBoards.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqiad8c011y2666cdggkm2y%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqibg3b01e32666uhyxb63t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqic1jr01zc2666v69oawpv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FBoards.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqici8e023p2666sofogdxa%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fmain.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqicquj02km2666d2jxy6t4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FPostForm.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqictwj02rg266623jhg1wt%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmjib341000h2666hix6st9v%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000h2666hix6st9v%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjibbip00mz266624c2t9w5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fbbs%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmjibbip00mz266624c2t9w5%2522%257D%252C%2522clmjib341000g26665tbxpsl6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib341000g26665tbxpsl6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmjj1nuu01ul2665rcmr8o62%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjib8kq00h72666nv8a5jdc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmjj1nuu01ul2665rcmr8o62%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clmpd6200004be6jo5k7e8b2q%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmqvpdoq0zy32666x6ie8fwb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

FORM COMPONENT

```
const OPTIONS = [
  {
    label: "general",
    value: "general",
  },
  {
    label: "anime",
    value: "anime",
  },
  {
    label: "gaming",
    value: "gaming",
  },
  {
    label: "music",
    value: "music",
  },
];

export default function PostForm({ addBulletin }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    comment: "",
    topic: OPTIONS[0].value,
  });
  const [topic, setTopic] = useState(OPTIONS[0].value);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const newId = Date.now();
    
    const newBulletin = {
      id: newId,
      ...formData,
    };
    
    addBulletin(newBulletin);
    
    console.log(formData.topic);
    setFormData({
      title: "",
      subtitle: "",
      comment: "",
      topic: OPTIONS[0].value,
    });

    setTopic(formData.topic);
  };

  function openForm() {
    setFormShow((formShow) => !formShow);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <label htmlform="title">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            id="title"
            minLength="3"
            required
            value={formData.title}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlform="topic">
          <select id="topic" name="topic" value={formData.topic} onChange={handleChange}>
          {OPTIONS.map(option => (
            <option
              key={option.value}
              value={option.value}
            >
              {option.label}
            </option>
          ))}
            
          </select>
        </label>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <label htmlform="message">
          <textarea
            name="comment"
            id="comment"
            minLength="3"
            required
            value={formData.comment}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>

        <button className="submit" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

BULLETIN BOARD COMPONENT

```
export default function Bulletins({topic}) {
  const [showPostForm, setShowPostForm] = useState(false);
  const [bulletins, setBulletins] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      topic: 'General',
      title: "Message board is alive!",
      comment: "Initial board post."
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      topic: 'General',
      title: "This Is a Post",
      comment: "This is a comment"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      topic: 'Gaming',
      title: "Sonic vs Mario",
      comment: "Who's the better character?"
    },
    
  ]);

  const addBulletin = (newBulletin) => {
    setBulletins([...bulletins, newBulletin]);
    console.log(newBulletin)
    console.log(bulletins);
    
    
    
  };
const btnstyle ={
  backgroundColor:'transparent',
  color: 'aqua',
  border: 'none',
}

  

  const filteredBulletins = bulletins.filter((bulletin) => bulletin.topic === topic);
  

  return (
    <>
      {filteredBulletins.map((bulletin, id) => (
        <Card
          key={id}
          topic={bulletin.topic}
          title={bulletin.title}
          // subtitle={bulletin.subtitle}
          comment={bulletin.comment}
          />
          ))}
          {showPostForm && <PostForm addBulletin={addBulletin} />}
          <button style={btnstyle} className="showform" onClick={() => setShowPostForm(true)}>Add Post</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code (minus the card component because I dont have that) and it is working for me if I change the filter function to:

```
bulletin.topic.toLowerCase() === topic.toLowerCase()
```

or update the value of the Options to have the first letter uppercase. It appears to be a case sensitivity issue when matching.